# Computing the overall charge of a compound with non-integer coefficients

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state

I have a question about computing the overall *charge* of inorganic chemicals, where the composition is expressed using non-integer stoichiometric coefficients.

Let's say we have $\ce{Hg_{0.7}Cd_{0.3}Te}$, and let $\text{ON}(\ce{X})$ be the oxidation number of element $\ce{X}$.

Then the approach I would follow is, *computing a weighted average of oxidation numbers of the elements in the composition, weighted by the fractional prevalence of the given element*. I know that there is often more than a single oxidation state but I'm not aware of rules according to I should consider one instead of the other. So what I would do is

$$0.7 \cdot \text{ON}(\ce{Hg}) + 0.3 \cdot \text{ON}(\ce{Cd}) + 1\cdot \text{ON}(\ce{Te})$$

and I'd expect the above computation to return $0$ in the case of a charge-neutral composition.

Now, is this approach correct? Maybe I should avoid considering the fractional prevalence and only consider the oxidation numbers?

Comment: Here, $\ce{Hg}$ and $\ce{Cd}$ are both at oxidation number $+2$. $\ce{Te}$ is at oxidation number $-2$.

Comment: oh got it, actually doing the computation in this particular case it exactly returns 0... so the fractional prevalence of the element must indeed be considered...?

Comment: @maurice This might be true for this specific compound if you know the compound, but the result does **not** generalise. If the question is *specifically* about this compound and nothing else, then fine. But that isn't how it is worded and, as such, your answer is likely to be very misleading in general.

Comment: My reasoning is valid if the coefficients of $\ce{Hg}$ and $\ce{Cd}$ are such that their sum is equal to the coefficient of $\ce{Te}$. It is the case here.

Comment: @matt_black so the way I've depicted in my question does not hold for a general composition?

Comment: In many compounds a given element may occupy different lattice sites with different nominal charges. To further complicate things, often vacancies are charged (with different sites having different charges ).

Comment: @JamesArten Not really. SAE 304 stainless steel is (approximately) Fe77Ni10Cr20Mn2Si1 and thinking about the oxidation state of the components is entirely unhelpful as it would be for most metal alloys. The major place where net charge might be useful is describing many silicate minerals where specific structures are known to have specific charges. But the formulae for those are already well-known. It is impossible to generalise across multiple compound classes.

Comment: @maurice But you are importing *specific* knowledge of this compound that *does not generalise*. It might be true here, but it could easily be true by accident in some metal alloy without the implications you assume.

Comment: Rather the opposite direction: There is given formal redistribution of charges in context of the definition of the oxidation number, with the zero net charge. Respective elements have formally such effective oxidation numbers for the charge inventory to match the zero net charge. So the charge neutrality is primary, ONs secondary.

Comment: James Arten never speaks of alloys. He only speaks of compounds.

Comment: Compounds with fractional coefficients are in fact solid solutions, which is pretty much the same as alloys.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So diamond is just solid solution and alloy of carbon-12 and carbon-13.

Comment: @Poutnik In a way, yes.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Downscaled to the usual macromolecular scale, macromolecules are just solid solutions and alloys of respective atoms, that just happen to be in ratio of relatively small integers.  :-)

Comment: @Ivan Neretin. Solid solutions are not similar to alloys. An alloy can have any sort of coefficients. It is not the case for a solid solution. In a solid solution the total of negative charges must be equal to the total of positive charges. This is the case for James Arten's compound $\ce{Hg_{0.7}Cd_{0.3}Te}$. And I repeat : it is a compound, not an alloy.